# ApiPlatform: override RouteNameGenerator

Tags: symfony, symfony4, api-platform.com

I am using singular path format and would like to have generated route names following the same logic for consistency and simplification.

It seems that this behavior is handled by ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Symfony\Routing\RouteNameGenerator

Basically for my use case, I just need to set false to the $pluralize parameter in

```php
RouteNameGenerator::inflector(string $name, bool $pluralize = true)
```

But it is never defined when called and all calls are statics.
The service override is not working

```php
//services.yaml
    ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Symfony\Routing\RouteNameGenerator:
        class: App\Operation\RouteNameGenerator
```

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Is it not working (not overriding at all), or it shows in container ar overridden, but still generates plural routes? I this You need to override `ApiPlatform\Core\Operation\Factory\SubresourceOperationFactory`, becouse there are calls like `RouteNameGenerator::inflector($operation['property'], $operation['collection'] ?? false)` which still set's plural to true

Comment: The override I tried is not working at all, just ignored (static call are not a service I guess).

I'm not using subResources for now, I may also try to override
`ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Symfony\Routing\RouterOperationPathResolver`.
  
It sounds over complicated for a simple parameter change :(
Ideally, I would like to disable all plural forms in this inflector function